# Ruby On Rails 3 problem sorting query results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, will-paginate

I'm trying to order my results in descending order by created_at date, but the order.clause doesn't seem to be working. I'm afraid I've been looking at this for entirely too long and could totally benefit from a second (or third or more) set of eyes.

`mailbox_controller.rb`:

```
def show  
  current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])  
  @folder = Folder.where("user_id = #{current_user.id}").first  
  @msgs = @folder.messages.order("created_at DESC")  
  @messages = @msgs.where(["deleted IS NULL"] || ["deleted = ?", false]).paginate :per_page => 5, :page => params[:page]  
end
```

Comment: Have you tried merging the last two lines of code into a single line (where first, then order? Just thinking that the "order" and "where" methods might be fighting with each other.

Answer (score 3):

```
@msgs = @folder.messages.order("created_at DESC")
@messages = @msgs.where(["deleted IS NULL"] || ["deleted = ?", false])
```

should be

```
@messages = @folder.messages.order("created_at DESC").where("deleted = ? or deleted IS NULL", false)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply fl00r, but it still doesn't sort by created_at DESC

Comment: @messages.map(&:created_at) -> NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! You might have expected an instance of Array. The error occurred while evaluating nil.map): app/controllers/mailbox_controller.rb:13:in `show' app/controllers/mailbox_controller.rb:5:in `index'

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it looks like the created_at you're going for belongs to Folder instead of messages.

Can you try with

```
@msgs = @folder.messages.order("messages.created_at DESC")
```